# How to save a two-dimensional array, as part of the variable inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a Component that holds some variables. Variables will be saved when restarting Unity. (int, color, float)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float startX = 0;
    public float startZ = 0;

    public int width = 1000;
    public int height = 1000;

    public float boxWidth = 32.0f;
    public float boxHeight = 32.0f;

    public float px;
    public float pz;

    public Color color = Color.white;
    public bool[,] map;

    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (map != null)
        {
            Vector3 pos = transform.position;

            px = pos.x + startX;
            pz = pos.z + startZ;

            Gizmos.color = color;

            Vector3 size = new Vector3(boxWidth, 0f, boxHeight);

            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
                {
                    if (map[x, z])
                    {
                        Gizmos.DrawCube(new Vector3(px + x * boxWidth, pos.y + 1, pz + z * boxHeight), size);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(new Vector3(px + x * boxWidth, pos.y + 1, pz + z * boxHeight), size);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To edit the variables I have my inspector:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

[CustomEditor (typeof(Grid))]
public class GridEditor : Editor
{
    Grid grid;

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        grid = (Grid)target;
        SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate += GridUpdate;

        if (grid.map == null)
        {
            grid.map = new bool[grid.width, grid.height];
            for (int x = 0; x < grid.width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < grid.height; y++)
                {
                    grid.map[x, y] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneView.onSceneGUIDelegate -= GridUpdate;
    }

    private int lastX = -1;
    private int lastZ = -1;
    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        Event e = Event.current;
        Camera camera = Camera.current;

        Vector3 mousePos =  Vector3.zero; // = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(e.mousePosition.x, e.mousePosition.y, distance));

        if (EventType.KeyDown == e.type && KeyCode.LeftControl == e.keyCode)
        {

            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(e.mousePosition.x, -e.mousePosition.y + camera.pixelHeight, 0));
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 2550f))
            {
                mousePos = hit.point;
            }

            int x = Mathf.RoundToInt((mousePos.x - grid.px)/grid.boxWidth);
            int z = Mathf.RoundToInt((mousePos.z - grid.pz)/grid.boxHeight);

            if (x >= 0 && x < grid.width && z >= 0 && z < grid.height)
            {
                if (x != lastX || z != lastZ)
                {
                    grid.map[x, z] = !grid.map[x, z];
                    lastX = x;
                    lastZ = z;
                    SceneView.RepaintAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label(" Start x ");
        grid.startX = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(grid.startX, GUILayout.Width(50));
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label(" Start z ");
        grid.startZ = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(grid.startZ, GUILayout.Width(50));
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();


        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label(" Grid Width ");
        grid.width = EditorGUILayout.IntField(grid.width, GUILayout.Width(50));
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label(" Grid Height ");
        grid.height = EditorGUILayout.IntField(grid.height, GUILayout.Width(50));
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label(" Box Width ");
        grid.boxWidth = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(grid.boxWidth, GUILayout.Width(50));
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label(" Box Height ");
        grid.boxHeight = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(grid.boxHeight, GUILayout.Width(50));
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Open Grid Window", GUILayout.Width(255)))
        {   
           GridWindow window = (GridWindow) EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof (GridWindow));
           window.Init();
        }

        SceneView.RepaintAll();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to store a two-dimensional array (map [,]) of boolean, so he remained when restarting Unity. All that I came it to make serialization to file and look for the file at startup App. (array can be a big 1000x20) Maybe you can advise a better idea? Thank you! Excuse my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually independent of the data types, e.g. Map, in your case. You can try ScriptableObject class, which does not need to be attached to some game object

Derive a class from ScriptableObject and add [Serializable] attribute to the class

```
[Serializable]
class MyData: ScriptableObject
{
     public bool[,] map;
     void OnEnable() { 
         //... do something to initialise the map or reload the map
     }
}
```

To instantiate an object for saving data

```
//in this case MyData contains your map data
var data = SciptableObject.CreateInstance(typeof(MyData));
```

To save it to the Unity database:

```
AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(data,  "Assets/SomeFolder/abc.asset");
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets()
AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

To check if some assets are already in the assets:

```
var data = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/SomeFolder/abc.asset",
    typeof(SomeData));
if(data != null) {
   //Your own logic to consume the map or whatever data
}
```

This way, all variables will be saved when Unity restarts, you might add [[InitializeOnLoad]](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html) attributes on your class to make it auto-load. And you can see abc.asset file inside unity, and using your custom Editor to edit the map is also a piece of cake.

Comment: And data from the editor (obtained Asset) will be available in the compiled version?

Comment: Absolutely right. Has tested this millions of times.

Comment: I have a problem with serialization. Can I show you some sample code?

Comment: For some reason it does not work with two-dimensional array. (one-dimensional saves)
This is normal?

Comment: I do not understand (. I did a one-dimensional array.
The data is saved when running, stop applications. But restarting the Unity, the data lost.

Comment: I forgot about SetDirty(grid.dataMap)

Comment: glad that you make it.

Comment: With only one-dimensional.